# Hashing session key

Tags: session, hash, .net-core

I'm attempting to hash a session key but I'm getting an error of *cannot convert from string to byte[]*

I'm assuming that the hash stores it in a byte array but why is it throwing errors on a session key variable.

```
var Sha1Hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();

var hash = Sha1Hash.ComputeHash(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string (`HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)`) into byte array

```
var hash = Sha1Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)));
```